# mocha test + istanbul coverage report takes only webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webpack, code-coverage, istanbul

I'm trying to run some test over my JS files.
`mocha` runs them without any problem, though I have a definition for aliases in my `.babelrc` file as follows:

```
"presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
"env": {
    "test": {
        "plugins": [
            [ "babel-plugin-webpack-alias", {
                "config": "./webpack.config.js"
            } ]
        ]
    }
}
```

for some reason, the code coverage of `istanbul` covers only the `webpack.config.js` file(??)

the `npm test` command which I run is:

```
istanbul cover --handle-siginit --hook-run-in-context  ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha  -- test/test.js --compilers js:babel-core/register  --require test/setup.js -R spec
```

(in the file `test.js` I define NODE_ENV: `process.env.NODE_ENV = "test";`)

in case relevant,
My code is written in `ES6` + `JSX` and I run just one test function

Cheers!